# Daemon threads are created when use jmx connection

Tags: java, daemon

In my program, from main program i am creating a worker thread which connects to server using JMX and gets mbeans,This worker thread internally creating daemon threads to get mbeans after getting mbeans i am stopping this worker thread but daemon threads or not closing when main thread is running, In my program main thread should n't stop , but every time worker thread created its daemon threads are created and not destroyed until my main thread stopped

Comment: use isDaemon() it will make you sure whether it is daemon thread or something else As I know without parent thread daemon cannot exists

Comment: I don't which daemon threads are created ... , they are internally created.